# JavaFX GridPane fixed row size

Tags: java, javafx, row, gridpane

I am working on a grammar analysis program. I am using a `GridPane` and have three `TextArea`s so far. The `TextArea` `paliVerse` should span over two rows; the `TextArea` `analysis` over four. However, when I change the `TextArea` `analysis` with

```
gridPane.add(analysis,2,1,4,1);
analysis.setPrefRowCount(4);
```

the `TextArea` `paliVerse` also spans over rows, even though the `PrefRowCount` is 2:

[image: current]

How can I change this so that it looks like:

[image: desired]

This is the relevant code:

```
package com.example.projektver180523;

import java.sql.*;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    private ComboBox<Integer> comboBox;
    private TextArea paliVerse;
    private TextArea paliVerseGER;
    private TextArea analysis;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws SQLException {

        // Erstelle die ComboBox
        comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

        // Fülle die ComboBox automatisch
        fillComboBox();

        // Erstelle die TextAreas
        paliVerse = new TextArea();
        paliVerseGER = new TextArea();
        analysis = new TextArea();

        // Textfeld ist unveränderlich
        paliVerse.setEditable(false);
        paliVerseGER.setEditable(false);
        analysis.setEditable(false);

        // 2 columns preferred
        paliVerse.setPrefColumnCount(2);
        paliVerseGER.setPrefColumnCount(2);

//        // 2 rows preferred for paliVerse and German translation textArea
        paliVerse.setPrefRowCount(2);
        paliVerseGER.setPrefRowCount(2);
        analysis.setPrefRowCount(4);

        GridPane.setConstraints(comboBox, 0, 1);
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();

        // Abstand nach innen setzen
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // horizontaler Abstand zwischen Kindern
        gridPane.setHgap(10);

        // vertikaler Abstand zwischen Kindern
        gridPane.setVgap(10);

        // Spalte 0 ist 150 weit
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(230));

        // Spalte 0 ist 480 weit
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(600));

        gridPane.add(new Label("Vers Nummer:"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(comboBox, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Palitext:"), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(paliVerse, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Übersetzung Deutsch:"), 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(paliVerseGER, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Analyse:"), 2, 0);
        gridPane.add(analysis, 2, 1, 4, 1);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 1200, 400);

        // Verknüpfe CSS-Datei
        scene.getStylesheets().add("styles.css");

        // Zeige das Hauptfenster an
        stage.setTitle("Dhammapada Reader");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, in case there's any confusion, the `TextArea.prefRowCount` property has nothing to do with how many rows of the `GridPane` the `TextArea` will span. That property tells the `TextArea` how to compute its preferred height based on the font. So, `analysis.setPrefRowCount(4)` is telling the `TextArea` to _preferably_ size itself to accommodate four rows of _text_ (though it may be smaller or bigger depending on its min/max height and on the parent layout).

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't aware ```setPrefRowCount()``` relates to the text.

Comment: _wasn't aware setPrefRowCount() relates to the text_ - what else could it possibly relate to, given it's api of textarea? Make sure you study the javadoc of each and every method you use!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be making this more complicated than it needs to be. Each cell in `GridPane` will be sized to accomodate the `Node` it contains, as stated in the class [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html):

> By default, rows and columns will be sized to fit their content; a column will be wide enough to accommodate the widest child, a row tall enough to fit the tallest child.

So all you need do is explicitly set the row span for [`TextArea`] `analysis` to 2 (two).
Consider the following code:
(Note that the actual contents of the `ComboBox` is irrelevant to your question so the below code does not populate the `ComboBox`. Besides, your question doesn't contain the code for method `fillComboBox` anyway.)

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    private ComboBox<Integer> comboBox;
    private TextArea paliVerse;
    private TextArea paliVerseGER;
    private TextArea analysis;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
        paliVerse = new TextArea();
        paliVerseGER = new TextArea();
        analysis = new TextArea();
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Vers Nummer:"), 0, 0);
        gridPane.add(comboBox, 1, 0);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Palitext:"), 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(paliVerse, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Übersetzung Deutsch:"), 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(paliVerseGER, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(new Label("Analyse:"), 2, 0);
        gridPane.add(analysis, 2, 1, 1, 2);
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 1200, 400);

        // Zeige das Hauptfenster an
        stage.setTitle("Dhammapada Reader");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: screen capture]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for posting the image. You are right, I made it too complicated.
Your remark regarding the ```ComboBox``` is also true. I will try to be more careful when posting code next time.
Greetings to Israel from Austria :)